# What is context in tomcat/conf/context.xml for? virtualhost?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, context.xml

I was reading a book (school book) on jsp and there was something I couldn't understand. In the book we had to execute a jsp page and for that they set a context in servlet.xml in tomcat 5.5:

```
<Context path="JSPTEST" docBase = "G:\Tomcat5.5"\webapps\JSPTEST"></Context>
```

and the jsp in that folder is accessed at `http://localhost:8080/JSPTEST/filename.jsp`

The first thing I realized is that the docBase is actually a webapp on the server so with or without setting this context it will still run on the same `url` so what's the point?

I installed a tomcat 7 and added a context to `conf/context.xml`

```
Context docBase="F:\work\bscit\serverside\practical" path="serverside" reloadable="true" />
```

I put hello.jsp under the `practical` folder restarted the tomcat and there was no response.server was down with [this in catalina_log](http://pastie.org/4354291). To me that's another way to set a virtualhost (I have a good idea on how to create a virtualhost under apache httpd) so am kind of confused right now.

**Question 1** what exactly context are used for ? I've had a look at [tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) it didn't ring the bell

**Question 2** how can I make the "same" thing work on tomcat 7 (without putting the file in tomcat of course)?

Answer (score 2):

1- A context is what describes a webb-app inside a web container. There you can define which path to use to access the web-app `path="JSPTEST"`, where the resources are located (the document base / root) `docBase = "G:\Tomcat5.5"\webapps\JSPTEST"` and other stuff such as JNDI resources for accessing database for example.

So the config you did in Tomcat 5 is to be read as follow:

When i ask the server for the path `JSPTEST` (witch is the root of your web app) he looks inside the physical directory defined in `docBase` of the corresponding context element. Once there the server looks than for the resource `filename.jsp` processes (since it is no static content, jsps need first to be compiled and run to generate html) and serves it to the client.

In the same way you can read the config made for Tomcat 7.

2- To be able to retrieve the resource `hello.jsp` from Tomcat 7 (or wahtever version) the url should be `http://localhost:8080/serverside/hello.jsp`

The name of the directory where the content is physically stored plays no role in the url for accessing the content. It is the combination between the elements `path` and `docbase`.

## Reply 2

Putting the context element inside the `conf/context.xml`, which itself has a `context` element as root is wrong and this is what is causing the error you are getting (an xml-parsing error while reading `conf/context.xml`). there are two ways to configure a web-app using the context.xml, take a look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html#A_word_on_Contexts) . Read point 1 and 2 carefully!

So to make things work:

Either

1- Put a file named `serverside.xml` with the content `<Context docBase="F:\work\bscit\serverside\practical" path="serverside" reloadable="true" ></Context>` in `conf/Catalina/localhost/`

Or

2- Create a directory inside `webapps` named `serverside` and put your jsps inside of it. In that case there is no need for a `serversid/META-INF/context.xml` file, unless you want to define other resources for the web-app, `docBase` and `path` elements may not appear in it.

Then call `http://localhost:8080/serverside/hello.jsp`

(1) is good for development, (2) is good for production.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply. i've actually tried already by hitting `http://localhost:8080/serverside/hello.jsp` but apparently the wholes server is down. here is the context configuration in `conf/context.xml` : `<Context docBase="F:\work\bscit\serverside\practical" path="serverside" reloadable="true" ></Context>` error is pasted here : http://pastie.org/4354291 . this is simplictic webapp without web-inf et al.

Comment: If the server was down then you wouldnt habe got HTTP 404 error ;-).

Comment: Yup you are right, it was a mistake from me. i edited the post it's down. not `404`. from the error in pastie you would notice that even ROOT is not loaded. thanks

Comment: I think that mus be something:
<Context docBase="F:/work/bscit/serverside/practical" path="serverside" reloadable="true" ></Context>